# Circuit for horizontal and vertical amplifier, homemade oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, crt

I want to make an oscilloscope with a small black and white TV (crt), currently disconnect the horizontal coil and with this circuit I can see the signals.

[image: horizontal amplifier circuit]

The problem with this is that only one half of the screen is used because it only receives the positive part of the signal, so I found this other circuit that I could use.

[image: new horizontal amplifier circuit]

But wouldn't this circuit be very inefficient? A lot of power would be lost in R1 if Q1 is running.

I also plan to make a sawtooth circuit with a 555 to control the horizontal and set the signal to the vertical.

My question is is there a better circuit? (that you can do without buying hard-to-find ICs) can the frequency of the tv's sawtooth generator be varied?

Comment: Where did you find this other circuit?

Comment: I found it at: https://webelectronica.com.ar/montajes2/nota48.htm

Comment: The circuit should be similar to that of an audio power amplifier output stage, and you can use designs optimized for that. Bipolar (+/-) supplies and a pair of complementary bipolar power transistors biased properly would be a straightforward approach. You would want current feedback.

Comment: Note that a TV tube usually uses magnetic deflection, as opposed to the typical oscilloscope tube which uses electrostatic deflection.  This is (probably) what's motivating Sphero's comment about wanting current feedback -- you want to control the _current_ to the coils, unless you have a really strange (for TV) CRT.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I thought about using an audio amplifier circuit but the ones I've seen only use positive voltage and if I want to use the other half of the screen I need the negative voltage too.

Comment: @TimWescott I don't quite understand how the difference affects me, from what I understood I won't be able to control time well enough to measure frequency. it is right?

Comment: Your first circuit may work if you exchange the "GND" points for "-12V".   You can only see the top half of waveforms because your amplifier here can't go below ground.

Comment: @user330326 Look at the writings of Douglas Self, for example.

Comment: "control time well enough to measure frequency": you appear to be confused.  You need to control the direction of an electron beam.

Comment: A speaker has AC in it produced by the push-pull output of an amplifier that goes positive and negative, sometimes coupled by a series output capacitor feeding the AC to the speaker..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very bad circuit. You need a properly designed voltage to current converter with 'push-pull' output.

First thing you should do is rotate the yoke (or the whole tube) so the vertical coils produce horizontal deflection. This puts the lower inductance horizontal coils where you need them to get best bandwidth.

Then you can use the normal vertical deflection circuit found in a TV to power the vertical coils (which are now moving the beam horizontally). Typically this uses a specialized 'vertical deflection' IC designed for the job.

If you want to develop your own circuit then [here](https://www.labguysworld.com/TheChief_005.htm) is an example.

[image]

The input voltage is converted to output current by producing a proportional feedback voltage across a small value 'current sense' resistor (R7, 36 Ω) in series with the coils. The op amp compares this voltage to the input and 'servos' the output until the input and feedback voltages are the same.

Apart from using current instead of voltage feedback it is similar to a class AB audio amplifier. As a bonus this circuit also includes the sawtooth generator.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for, I didn't want to use the TV circuit because the frequency is fixed.